Time Validation Function - VBA
I have been trying to create a function in VBA to validate time format as hh:mm:ss for a column in my spreadsheet. I am basically trying to ensure that values in this column are in the right format, that is why i am creating a function which i will use in my validation. I will appreciate any help!
I tried this function below last but it is still identifying my time as incorrect.
Function IsTime(x As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    ' Regex pattern to match time format xx:yy:zz
    regex.Pattern = "^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$"
    
    ' Test the input string against the pattern
    IsTime = regex.Test(x)
End Function


How is your cell formatted and what is the real content of the cell? Do the cell contains  real times (in that case it's a date, and dates are stored as numbers), or is it a String that looks like a time value? Have you checked with the debugger what x contains? I assume that it contains the numeric value of the date, converted to a string, so for example 0.25 instead of 06:00:00

IsDate should do: If IsDate(x) Then ....

@FunThomas my cell is formatted as time. I input real times (e.g 22:30:45 , 12:20:13 etc). I also tried this function but it only verifies 12:00:00 time
Function IsValidTimeFormat(timeStr As String) As Boolean     On Error GoTo InvalidTime     Dim t As Date     t = TimeValue(timeStr)     IsValidTimeFormat = True     Exit Function InvalidTime:     IsValidTimeFormat = False End Function

@Gustav i tried using IsDate as well, but it didn't work either.

It does. IsDate("22:30:45") will return True; and so will both of your functions. Thus, something else is going on.
